# removeAll(closure) in Swift

Tags: swift, closure

From [this](https://github.com/vrwim/Swift-Extensions) library I wrote, I have created this function in Swift, but I'm not happy with the implementation. Can anyone suggest a better way to do this? I really don't like changing counters inside `for`-loops...

```
extension Array {

    /// Removes all items that conform to the given closure
    mutating func removeAll(closure: (T) -> Bool) {
        for var counter = 0; counter < count; counter += 1 {
            if closure(self[counter]) {
                removeAtIndex(counter)
                counter -= 1
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some general remarks:

- The method name `removeAll` is misleading, as it does not remove
  all elements from the array. I would call it for example `removeMatching`.
- The method parameter is a closure, but acts as a predicate, so
  `predicate` might be a better name.
- The `counter` variable in the method is actually the array index
  so you could call it `index`.
- The method documentation can be improved (details at the end of
  this answer).

Your concrete problem about modifying the loop counter inside the
loop can easily be solved by traversing the array indices in 
reverse order:

```
for var index = count - 1; index >= 0; index-- { ... }
```

Using `stride()` allows you to have a *constant* loop variable:

```
for index in stride(from: count - 1, through: 0, by: -1) { ... }
```

Putting it all together:

```
extension Array {

    /// Removes all items that satisfy the predicate:
    mutating func removeMatching(predicate: (T) -> Bool) {
        for index in stride(from: count - 1, through: 0, by: -1) {
            if predicate(self[index]) {
                removeAtIndex(index)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

An alternative implementation would be

```
extension Array {

    /// Removes all items that satisfy the predicate:
    mutating func removeMatching(predicate: (T) -> Bool) {
        self = self.filter { !predicate($0) }
    }
}
```

The first method removes the matching elements, while the second method
creates a new array and then replaces `self`. Which one is more 
efficient depends how many elements are actually removed in relation
to the array size.

Notice that in Swift 2, `Element` should be used in place of `T`.

As mentioned above, the inline method documentation can be improved
(I took this information from the SO thread [Swift Documentation Comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27715933/swift-documentation-comments)). Example:

```
extension Array {
    /// Removes all items that satisfy the `predicate`
    ///
    /// :param: predicate A boolean predicate.
    mutating func removeMatching(predicate: (T) -> Bool) {
        self = self.filter { !predicate($0) }
    }
}
```

Now "Option-Click" will show you

[image]

---

**Addendum:** A [`removeAll(where:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/rangereplaceablecollection/3018275-removeall) was added to the Swift Standard library in **Swift 4.2,** so there is no need to define your own method for that purpose anymore.

As explained in [SE-0197](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0197-remove-where.md) this method is supposed to be both safe and efficient.

Comment: I agree with all points, especially the last using `filter`, but what is the advantage of using `stride()`?

Comment: Ooh I was looking at using better documentation, and I was looking at @param, but that didn't seem to work, thanks!

Comment: @vrwim: The advantage is that `index` is a *constant* inside the loop so that you cannot inadvertently modify it. Using a constant *may* also allow better compiler optimizations.

Comment: @MartinR ok, thanks! I will test out the `filter` vs my implementation for speed and I'll get back to you

Comment: Holy moly; When using [this code](http://pastebin.com/iuCjNjfn) (where `removeMatching` is your last code), I get [this result](http://pastebin.com/7e7aRWcW), which is like 4-5 times slower.

Comment: @vrwim: Did you run the code in the "Release" configuration to enable optimizations?  There seems also to be flaw in your test method: When `array.removeMatching()` is called, all matching elements have already been removed in the preceding `array.removeAll()`.

Comment: I fixed the flaw, and ran in "Release, my code is slower by factor 10 :(